# Control point to create bezier curve

Tags: javascript, coordinates, bezier, curve

I get two (xy) coordinates dynamically, one defining the start and another defining the end of a curve. In order to generate a Bezier curve between them, I want to define a third (xy) coordinate as control - with a third point, I can draw a a Bezier curve perfectly, but my problem is that I do not know how to *get* the coordinate for the control point (xy).

For a line drawed by the xy start point and the xy end point (black line) I find one point in the coords xy (yellow circle) formed by the cross of drawing a intersection line (green line) in the middle of the line given and a 45 degrees staring in the xy start point (red line).

I added a image example to explain it better.

[image]

Comment: I've rewritten your question as best I could, because it didn't make a lot of sense the way you wrote it. If this really is your question: you'll have to add more details, because there are an infinite number of possible control points. There is no reason to pick the one you've shown in your figure, for instance. You need to explain the conditions that apply to either the control point (at least D away from both points, or equidistant to them, etc. etc.) or to the curve itself (the tangents need to be at least F, or the minimum curvature needs to be at most R, etc. etc.) first.

Comment: I give your advice and edit my answer for another more clear. Hope it helps

Comment: I'm afraid it's not. So let's figure this out: you have two points (please show those to in your image, and label them `A=x1,y1` and `B=x2,y2` or something), and a line through them (already in the image). You then show a red and green line, but _why_ are you showing them? Are you specifically asking how to create curves that departs the starting point at 45 angles, and then arrive at the end point at a 45 degree angle (due to the symmetries in your picture)? If so, that shouldn't need our help, you've already found the control point (it's that yellow circle).

Comment: Sorry I think that i'm not explain myself clearly, I want to know how (or the best way) to find the point in yellow circle, because I don't have idea to get this point dinamically.

Comment: I edited the picture for another a bit descriptive

Comment: If you know start, end, you also know every coordinate that's on the blue line, and because of the definition for the red line, you also know every coordinate on the red line (note: on the infinite line, not just line segment). So, to find the yellow point you simply find the code for "finding the intersection of two lines" online (there are _so_ many examples of that online already) and then you apply that. Yellow point found.

Comment: the problem is that I don't have the blue line, only the black line

Comment: no, I'm pretty sure you have the blue line: it's perpendicular to {start,end} and goes through the midpoint, so we know that the point `(start+end)/2` is on the blue line. So we know the line itself is defined as `that point, plur or minus N times its directional vector`. And we know that vector: it's just the original line, rotated 90 degrees (which is stupidly simple to calculate: `(dx,dy)` becomes `(-dy, dx)`, the end). We are done: we know the blue line.